# How to create a file in multiple directories in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm just doing this as an exercise in Linux but, I was wondering how could i use `touch` to create one empty file and have it exist in multiple directories.

For example i have a directory layout like the followng:

```
~/main
~/main/submain1
~/main/submain2
.
.
.
~/main/submainN
```

How could i get the file created by `touch` to exist in all of the `submain` directories? My first thought is to have a loop that visits each directory using `cd` and call the `touch` command at every iteration. I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

What about this:

```
find . -type d -exec touch {}/hiya \;
```

this will work for any depth level of directories.

#### Explanation

```
find . -type d -exec touch {}/hiya \;
```

- `find . -type d` --> searchs directories in the directory structure.
- `-exec touch {}/hiya \;` --> given each result, its value is stored in `{}`. So with `touch {}/hiya` what we do is to touch that "something"/hiya. The final `\;` is required by `exec` in `find` clauses.

Another example of `find` usage:

```
find . -type d -exec ls {} \;
```

#### Test

```
$ mkdir a1
$ mkdir a2
$ mkdir a3
$ mkdir a1/a3
```

Check dirs:

```
$ find . -type d
.
./a2
./a1
./a1/a3
./a3
```

Touch files

```
$ find . -type d -exec touch {}/hiya \;
```

Look for them:

```
$ find . -type f
./a2/hiya
./hiya
./a1/hiya
./a1/a3/hiya
./a3/hiya
```

And the total list of files/dirs is:

```
$ find .
.
./a2
./a2/hiya
./hiya
./a1
./a1/hiya
./a1/a3
./a1/a3/hiya
./a3
./a3/hiya
```

Answer (score 6):

If your directory naming structure is numbered like your example IRL you could do the following:

```
touch ~/main/submain{1..N}/file.txt
```

This would put file.txt in every folder named submain1 through to submainN

If they're not numbered 1-N you could also try:

```
touch ~/main/{foldername,differentfolder,anotherfolder}/file.txt
```

This is a less general solution than the above but may be more understandable for learners!